# perforce server settings

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to set the Perforce server to by default don't let the users check out a directory, instead of letting everybody update their view-spec to exclude that directory?

Eg: if you would like to check out //code/heavy/stuff you must explicitly add that directory to your view-spec instead of adding a -//code/heavy/stuff yo your spec.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a trigger on the server that generates the default clientspec for a user. With this flexible tool, you can achieve a number of designs. The idea is that when a user creates a new clientspec, the server would fill it in with something other than the default //depot/... mapping for each depot.

One simple idea would be to define the default clientspec to include -//code/heavy/stuff mapping automatically.

Another more advanced idea would be to check to see what groups the user is a member of, and then auto-generate a clientspec appropriate for that user based on his group membership.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to block people from getting it, then it might be possible with permission mapping.

But then they would never by able to access it, even if they change their client spec.

Maybe you need to (re-)structure your repository so that the heavy part isn't in most users' client specs.